# vinegar in lollipops

Tags: candy

How much vinegar can I use in a lollipop recipe without upsetting the  "setting up" of the candy?  There is a remedy for hiccups that uses sugar and vinegar as an instant cure and I desperately need to try to get as much vinegar into the mix as I can.  Never made candy before!  Please help.

Comment: mmmmmm...vinegar

Comment: Why don't you just eat vinegar and sugar... why make it into a candy? What is this recipe, anyway?

Comment: @lemontwist: Have you ever had sour patch kids, sour soothers, sour gummies, etc.? They're coated with, basically, a mixture of sugar and citric acid. Although I'm not sure I'd make entire candies out of sugar and vinegar, I'm guessing the taste wouldn't be all that different from the citric acid used in those commercial candies.

Comment: @aaronut, vinegar would be great for "sour patch pickles" (lol!) but not a great substitute for the kind of tart taste made with citric acid. (IMO, of course)

Comment: @lemontwist - Vinegar Pie is a thing: http://bkcreative.hubpages.com/hub/What-is-a-Vinegar-Pie

Answer (score 5):

From what I could fine in a cursory search of recipes, the [typical](http://www.cooks.com/rec/view/0,177,144172-251198,00.html) [ratio](http://pioneerwomanatheart.blogspot.com/2011/11/cider-vinegar-candy.html) for [vinegar](http://www.cyber-kitchen.com/ubbs/archive/MEMORIAL/Connie%27s_Grandma%27s_Vinegar_Candy.html) candy is 4:1, sugar to vinegar, usually done as 2 cups sugar, 1/2 cup vinegar.

The highest ratio I found was 3 cups sugar to 1 1/2 cups vinegar ([Dottie's Vinegar Candy Recipe](http://www.cooks.com/rec/view/0,167,149177-248204,00.html)).  That, however, was specifically for a soft candy--taffy.

I'm not sure whether the higher ratio means that that mixture could not reach hard ball stage if heated high enough or if it's merely the choice of the recipe writer to make a softer candy.